# updating events in jquery fullcalendar with django view on clicking prev button

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, fullcalendar

Based on [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069997/using-jquery-fullcalendar-in-django-app/10089534#10089534) by @demalexx  ,I created the code to show number of posts created by a user of my django app, in jquery fullcalendar.I put the calendar in index.html and created the django view to populate events data.

index.html

```
...
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       events: {{posts_counts|safe}}
});
...
```

django view

```
    def index(request){
      now=datetime.datetime.now()
      cday=now.day
      cmonth=now.month
      cyear=now.year
      for i in range(1,cday+1):
        posts_count.append({'title':str(Post.objects.filter(postauthor=request,user,posteddate__year=current_year,posteddate__month=current_month,posteddate__day=i).count()),'start':now.strftime("%Y-%m-"+str(i)),'end':now.strftime("%Y-%m-"+str(i))})}
      return render(request, 'index.html',{'posts_counts':simplejson.dumps(posts_counts)})
```

In urls.py ,I have put the url as

```
url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.index',{}, name = 'home'),
```

Now,things work as expected.When I go to the homepage (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/`),the each day of the current month shows the number of posts created on that day

**Question::How to do the same on clicking the prev ,next buttons?**

I wanted to do the same on click of `prev` and `next` buttons.So,I decided to call another django view, passing the month and year as returned by `fullCalendar('getDate')` method.I coded like this.

index.html

```
...
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: {{entry_count|safe}}
            });

            $('.fc-button-prev').click(function(){

                var d=$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                var month=d.getMonth()+1;
                var year=d.getFullYear();              
                    //need to call django view with these values...        
            $.ajax({
         url:'/myapp/monthly_posts/'+year+'/'+month,
             type:"GET",
             success:function(){
             alert("done");                         
            },
          }
        );
        });

            $('.fc-button-next').click(function(){
                   //alert('next is clicked, do something');
                       //blank for now
                });

        });
```

Finally,I coded the django view to handle this get request-which is sent on clicking the prev button

```
def monthly_posts(request,year,month):
    print 'monthly_posts::year=',year,' month=',month    
    posts_counts=[]
    #find number of days in month and feed to forloop
    days_in_month=calendar.monthrange(int(year), int(month))[1]
    for i in range(1,days_in_month+1):
        cdate=datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),i)
        posts_counts.append({
                              'title':str(Post.objects.filter(postauthor=request.user,posteddate__year=year,posteddate__month=month,posteddate__day=i).count()),
                              'start':cdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                              'end':cdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                              })
    dumped=simplejson.dumps(posts_counts)
    print 'dumped posts=',dumped
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'posts_counts':dumped})
```

Also in urls.py

```
url(r'^monthly_posts/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/$','myapp.views.monthly_posts',{})
```

Here is when things don't work fully..When,prev button is clicked,the alert box pops up as expected and then the django view is executed,the print statement in `monthly_posts()` gets the correct values (suppose today is `april 11`, and I click on `prev` button ,the print statement prints

monthly_posts::year= 2012  month= 3

which is correct ..ie 2012 march ,since my javascript code adds a 1 to the month number (which is otherwise 2 for march-because of 0 based `javascript date.getMonth()` )

and it also outputs the json dump correctly at the last print statement in the view..I checked for the Posts made in that month.No problem there.

However,the calendar view for month of March doesnot show any events!

When I manually entered the url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/monthly_posts/2012/3/
```

print statements in django view executes correctly

```
month_summary::year= 2012  month= 3
```

but,the month view is still that of current month ie April..I guess that is to be expected..
Surprise comes when I click the prev button,
the alert box pops up correctly ,

and the month view for march shows all days with the events correctly..!

I am a bit confused by this..What do I have to do to get the events displayed properly on clicking prev button?I guess I am missing some fundamental thing here about the way ajax and django work.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax in Django view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        return get_monthly_posts(request.GET['start'], request.GET['end'])
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Prepare response:

```
def get_monthly_posts(start, end):
    #prepare data_list using start nad end variables
    #remember that start/end variables are in timestamp

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data_list), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^index/', 'myapp.views.index', name='index')
```

index.html:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/index/'
});
```