# Unable to display the events on fullcalendar in django app

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, fullcalendar

Following the same steps as mentioned in [using jquery fullcalendar in django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069997/using-jquery-fullcalendar-in-django-app/25679734#25679734), I am still unable to display my events on the calendar itself. Need some advice on this!! I am kind of new to this and hope to get some help! Thanks!!

This is my view.py.

```
def viewSchedule(request):
    posts_counts = []
    for i in (1, 31):
        posts_counts.append({'title': str(i), 'start': '2014-09-%d' % i, 'end': '2014-09-%d' % i})
    return render(request, 'ESSS/viewSchedule.html',
        {'posts_counts': simplejson.dumps(posts_counts)})
```

This is my html page.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='/static/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/static/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script> 
<script src='/static/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events: {{ posts_counts|safe }} 
        });
    });
</script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

At this moment, whenever I try to load my page, I am able to get the calendar up, but the events are not loaded in.

Comment: When you see rendered page source code, has `events` right values? (like: `...events: [{ title: 'All Day Event',  start: '2014-09-01'  },... `)? Any javascript error on console?